# Macro with variable length of parameters

Tags: c, gcc

Is there a way to `#define` a macro with variable length of parameters?

```
#define CALL(ar1, ar2, ar3)
do something
#endif
```

in C code

```
CALL(0);
CALL(0,1);
CALL(0,1,2)
```

all invoke the above CALL macro. If ar2, ar3 not used, preprocessor just ignore the line with ar2 or ar3.

Comment: please search SO or the web before asking, just putting "macro with variable length of parameters" in my favorite search engine brings a lot of results.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, take a look at this one: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html

Key word is `__VA_ARGS__` ( Variadic Macros ):

A macro can be declared to accept a variable number of arguments much as a function can. The syntax for defining the macro is similar to that of a function. Here is an example:

```
 #define eprintf(...) fprintf (stderr, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: I read this. it's not the one I want. this require the macro body has functions that take __VA_ARGS__.